# What is path origin for relative paths in Scene#getStylesheets()?

Tags: java, css, javafx

It is not documented where is origin location for relative paths in [`getStylesheets()` javadoc](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--). It is partially documented in ["JavaFX CSS Reference Guide"](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introscenegraph), but description is controversal.

For example it is said:

> A style sheet URL may be an absolute URL or a relative URL. If a
>   relative URL is given, it is resolved against the base URL of the
>   ClassLoader of the concrete Application class. If, for example, there
>   is a main class com.wicked.cool.ui.Main that extends Application, the
>   relative URL "/com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css" would resolve
>   correctly, as would "com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css". The
>   relative URL "../resources/styles.css" would not since the path ".."
>   relative to the root is not a valid path. It is often easier to use
>   the ClassLoader of some class to find the resource. For example, if
>   the "styles.css" file resides in the same package as Main, the
>   following code will give the correct URL:
>   com.wicked.cool.ui.Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm().

I.e. an example of "relative" URL is "/com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css", which is not relative, but absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Note that both

```
/com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css
```

and

```
com/wicked/cool/resources/styles.css
```

are relative URLs as defined in [RFC1808](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1808.txt).

Relative here means relative to the location the `ClassLoader` uses to resolve the URLs. (Both URLs are missing the authority/protocol part.)

The following example uses `URLClassLoader` to add a new location to find the stylesheet:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        File stylesheetDir = ...

        // classloader able to resolve additional resources located at the given dir
        ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {stylesheetDir.toURI().toURL()}, Main.class.getClassLoader());
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> Application.launch(TestApplication.class, new String[0]));

        // specify classloader to use
        thread.setContextClassLoader(classLoader);

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Assuming `TestApplication` has the following start method:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new Rectangle(100, 100)));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/style.css");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

and `style.css` being a css file located only at the specified directory containing the following:

```css
* {
    -fx-fill: red;
}
```

The `Rectangle` will appear red.

Now comment out

```
thread.setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
```

And you'll get the default black `Rectangle` as well as a warning.